# Problem to connect postgres with karate running in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, visual-studio-code, karate

I followed the instructions of https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Docker to run the karate-chrome Docker image and worked it fine.

But when i try to connect karate with my local server of postgres i have the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

I have the postgres server running with the host and port correct (localhost:5432). And I'm using the following configuration for the JDBC API:

```
Background: 
* def config = { username: 'postgres', password: 'pass', url: 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database_name_here', driverClassName: 'org.postgresql.Driver' }
* def DbUtils = Java.type('Testapi.DbUtils')
* def db = new DbUtils(config)
```

Anyone have any suggestions to solve this problem?. Thank you in advance.

Note: When i use a mysql online server everything runs fine (with its respective configuration).

Comment: this seems very specific to your environment, so I think you need to figure this out on your own. I think you need to take the help of some Docker expert, for example on how to expose ports you need  to use